# why use 述べ instead of 述べる

Tags: grammar

i don't really know why the stem version was used instead of the dict version in this sentence is it because of the の? or is there a grammar rule i am missing?

次の慣用句の続きを述べよ 風が吹けば…

Comment: Can you attempt a translation or at least edit your question to indicate **what you think this sentence means**? I suspect that you are in fact misinterpreting the grammar. If so, this may help: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6833/difference-between-一段-imperatives-～よ-～ろ

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between 一段 imperatives ～よ・～ろ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6833/difference-between-%e4%b8%80%e6%ae%b5-imperatives-%ef%bd%9e%e3%82%88-%ef%bd%9e%e3%82%8d)

Comment: See this table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Japanese#Conjugation_table