# What is this よ in 値を求めよ?

Tags: conjugations

Here is a sentence which would appear in a math exam paper.

> Xの値を求めよ。(Find the value of X.)

What kind of conjugation is this 求めよ and how does it work?

Comment: Related: [Difference between 一段 imperatives ～よ・～ろ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6833/5010)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you probably know, 求める is an ichidan verb, and the imperative form you encounter most commonly is 求めろ. But if we delve deeper into 活用, it also has another [imperative form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_verb_conjugation#%E5%91%BD%E4%BB%A4%E5%BD%A2) (命令形), more formal in register and more literary in style: 求めよ.

The conjugation of 求める falls under [下一段活用](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8B%E4%B8%80%E6%AE%B5%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8). So to answer your question: 求めよ is 求める's literary imperative form.